# method of least square proof

Tags: regression, computational-mathematics

$$Q(\beta_0, \beta_1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1X_i)^2$$

I'm trying to understand the proof in my notes and it does this

$$\frac{dQ(\beta_0, \beta_1)}{d\beta_0} = 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1X_i)$$

Shouldn't it be

$$\frac{dQ(\beta_0, \beta_1)}{d\beta_0} = (2)(-1) \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1X_i)$$

since $(Y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 X_i) = (0 - 1 + 0) = (-1)$

Comment: As written at the moment you are right. But could it be that in your notes the expression in the sum is inverted? Hence, maybe the minus sign is absorbed into the expression in the sum.

Comment: basically, you take partial derivative from $(Y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i)^2$ with respect to $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ and set them equal to zero. So you should look at the process as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree:$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_0}\sum_i(Y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i)^2=\sum_i\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_0}(\beta_0+\beta_1X_i-Y_i)^2\\=2\sum_i(\beta_0+\beta_1X_i-Y_i)=-2\sum_i(Y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i).$$My guess is it's a misprint resulting from the fact that we'll set the derivative to $0$, so for any $k\ne0$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_0}\sum_i(Y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i)^2=0\iff k\sum_i(Y_i-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i)=0.$$